# Animate.CSS Transition not working in Mozila Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Trying to Slide only `h3` (not whole slider) `bounceInLeft` using Animate.CSS but it's working only Chrome,opera *but not working on Firefox browser.*

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/10/) > on Chrome, then Firefox.

CSS:

```
/******************
* Bounce in Left *
*******************/
@keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.animated.bounceInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    animation-name: bounceInLeft;
}

/****************
* bounceInRight *
****************/
@keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -o-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.animated.bounceInRight {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    -o-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    animation-name: bounceInRight;
}

/* Description */
#headslide p {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-o-animation-name:bounceInRight;
animation-name:bounceInRight;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;

box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-o-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-ms-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

margin:0;
}

/* Title */
#headslide h3 {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-o-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;

background: #fff;
font-size: 110%;
line-height: 1.4;
padding: 1% 2%;
margin: 0;
font-weight:normal;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

This Slider has a fade transition by default, so it shows fade transitions on Firefox and my `bounceInLeft/bounceInRight` keyframes only work on Chrome and Opera.
I'm only trying to slide `h3`, and not the entire Slider.

Why does Animate.css not work on Firefox? How can I fix this? 
 Is it possible to fix this using jQuery? Thanks.